# Where to find nm tool (compiled or source code) for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, toolchain

I want to create an application that is able to list all symbols of a dynamic library .so file in Android. I want to ask if there is precompiled nm for Android or at least nm's source code so that I can compile it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nm` is part of [binutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/). You can get the source code from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils.

You can also find arm supporting binary (compiled for host, linux-x86) in [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html).

If you need a binary for Android target, you can try to build it by obtaining latest Android repository, navigating to external/elfutils. However I don't think there is an Android.mk building it, so it might not be trivial. You can see that nm.c on [github mirror of Android repository](https://github.com/android/platform_external_elfutils/blob/master/src/nm.c).

Comment: thanks, the mirror link on github for Android is exactly what I need

Answer (score 6):

nm is available in all ndk toolchains, for example:
< ndk >/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm