# Runtime error when run android app with ndk

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I tried run my android app with c++ code (NDK). file libF.so is made. app without errore run but 
get "unfortunately has stopped". I've used try and catch but not message. I've even cleared body of C++ function. 
I do not know what to do And I do not know where is the problem.

I'm not good in English, Please forgive me

My java code is :

```
public class main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    static{
        System.loadLibrary("F");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try{
            mainc();

        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("lee", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static native void mainc();
}
```

c++ code (F.cpp):

```
#include <jni.h>
#define JNIIMPORT
    #define JNIEXPORT  __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
#define JNICALL

using namespace std;
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_opencv_filter_main_mainc(JNIEnv * jenv, jclass){}
```

Answer (score 2):

The function must be declared as

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_opencv_filter_main_mainc(JNIEnv * jenv, jclass);
```

If this does not fix the problem, please add more info about what you see in logcat when you try to run. Is your package actually **com.opencv.filter.main**?

You can run [`nm -D`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971357/where-to-find-nm-tool-compiled-or-source-code-for-android) on your **libF.so** to find how exactly C++ mangled the name of your **manic()** function.

Comment: the problem do not fix, I get Photo from log cat, URL = http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2014/10/03/log.png

Comment: My package name = com.opencv.filter. "main" is name class. Previously in use c programming in android (native) Similarly Name. Here I use C++ programming

Comment: There is `nm` executable in NDK toolchain bin directory. Try it with `-D` on your **libF.so**. You will see how C++ mangle the name of your **mainc** function.